# Independence of random projection of Gaussian random vector

Tags: normal-distribution, projection

If $v$, $y$ and $h$ are independent Gaussian random vectors, are $|v^H y|^2$ and $|v^H h|^2$ independent?

Comment: Welcome to our site! This is an interesting question but I have a query about the superscript H: this is generally used for the [conjugate transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose), which suggests you are considering complex-valued vectors. But there is nothing else in your question that indicates this. Could you clarify whether you intend your vectors to be real or complex? (If real, I think superscript t or T, or even just a "prime" `'` might be less confusing.)

Answer (score 3):

Consider the case of 1-vectors where $v, h$, and $y$ have standard Normal distributions (whence their second moments equal $1$ and fourth moments equal $3$).  If $(vh)^2$ and $(vy)^2$ were independent, then their expectations would multiply:

$$\mathbb{E}((vh)^2(vy)^2) = \mathbb{E}((vh)^2)\mathbb{E}((vy)^2) = \mathbb{E}(v^2)\mathbb{E}(h^2)\mathbb{E}(v^2)\mathbb{E}(y^2) = (1)(1)(1)(1)=1.$$

(The second equality follows from the assumed independence of both $(v,h)$ and $(v,y)$.)

However, by virtue of the independence of $(v,h,y)$ we may easily compute

$$\mathbb{E}((vh)^2(vy)^2) = \mathbb{E}(v^4 h^2 y^2) = \mathbb{E}(v^4)\mathbb{E}(h^2)\mathbb{E}(y^2) = (3)(1)(1)=3.$$

Since $3\ne 1$, the independence assumption in the first calculation must be false: $(vh)^2$ cannot be independent of $(vy)^2$.

Independence fails for $n$-vectors in general, for much the same reason: when $|v|$ is large, both $|v^\prime h|$ and $|v^\prime y|$ will tend to be large; and when the former is small, both the latter expressions will tend to be small.  Although they are *conditionally* (on $v$) independent, they are not independent.

Comment: You're not concerned that you just gave a detailed solution to what might be a homework or take-home test problem?

Comment: @Mark Such a concern is valid and is to be respected in obvious cases.  If it were extended unilaterally to less-obvious cases, as here, we might answer very few questions at all!

Comment: obviousness is in the eyes of the beholder. I originally thought this case was obvious. Now I've given it 10 minutes thought, a la G.H. Hardy, and concluded, yes, it's obvious.